# How to perform for loop in nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, nightwatch.js

I wanted to test a scenario where for loop is needed. Can you guys me an example for loop?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
browser
   .perform(function(){
      add java script here
   })
```

also there is lots of documents about nightwatch in this link
"http://nightwatchjs.org/api" i hope this helps

Comment: you can use nightwatch commands from the link i provided in my answer instead of javascript codes.